# Find is not a function error

Tags: javascript, find

I have an array of objects in javascript like this:

```
array=[{label: 1, value:e}, {label:1, value: i}, {label: 2, value:l}]
```

I want to find the label when value is l so I'm writing:

```
array.map((i) => i.find(item => item.value === 'l').label)
```

But an error is returning

> i.find is not a function

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the second code line complete? Seems to me you are missing a `(` somewhere.

Comment: Yes an ( is missing. My mistake but the error is still here

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you are using `map`- based on your question you are just trying to find the label of the element with a particular value, so all you need is `find`. This works fine:

`array.find(item => item.value === 'l').label`

Returns `2`.

You should handle the case where `find` returns `undefined`, for example:

```
var found = array.find(item => item.value === 'l')
if(found){
  var label = found.label;
  // use label
}else{
  // nothing found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `i` becomes `{label: 1, value:e}`, then moves on to your next objects from the array. Those objects don't have a `.find` method. Instead, you can simply use the `i.value` to extract the information.

If you only want to produce an output for *some* of the elements, you need to `filter` them first, then `map`:

```
let labels = array
  .filter(i => i.value === 'l')
  .map(i => i.label)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the map function before your find, please see the documentation on the two function

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

I believe to achieve the outcome you desire you just want to use the find on it's own.

In your example code the *i* variable is the object within your array not an array.